# onbackpressed for gallery intent ,Android

Tags: android, button, android-activity, gallery, back-button

In my app , I select an image from gallery using startactivity for result. my code as follows

```
GALLERY.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0 );

        }
    });
```

it all works fine, but the problem is ,when in gallery if i press back button , my app closes and returns me to home screen. For a normal activity there is a method called OnbackPressed to handle back button.But How do i achieve this in Gallery activity.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to handle BackButton

1)

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            // Do Some thing Here
            return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

2)

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Do Some thing Here
        super.onBackPressed();

}
```

Comment: note that if you don't want to close you shouldn't call the super.onBackPressed.  It is likely you will need to make some logic that determines when the super will be called.

Comment: I'd also prefer using onBackPressed, that way any weird things that could happen in the keyboard or hardware configuration will be taken care of.

Comment: my problem is, where do I use this onbackpressed button. This method works for normal activity. but how do i use it in onstaractivityforresult.

Comment: when I get into phones gallery, when i press back button. I get outside the app. I mean it closes the app.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was your own custom gallery implementation.  You can't change how another app functions like that.

Comment: there might be some other way to do that. I couldnt find any suggestions online.

Comment: Yes, you may be able to start the gallery activity and then start another invisible activity immediately on top of it to handle the back press, but I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: please check if you have your activity set as single instance or so in  the manifest, generally pressing back from the gallery intent should lead you back to the calling intent. check how you are overriding onActivityResult()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ACTION_PICK intent :

```
    Intent intentImage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);startActivityForResult(intentImage, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);


    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
switch (requestCode) {
    case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
               Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
               String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
               Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
               cursor.moveToFirst();
               int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
               Path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
               setImage(Path);
               Toast.makeText(this, "File Clicked: "+picturePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               cursor.close();
           }  
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Surrounding the intent into a try and catch helped me. If there's an exception, like pressing the back button, I intent back to the activity i was at previously.

Answer (score 0):

Please handle result code first before handle request code

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA) {
    //your code
}
```